# Count Rows in a Specific range

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a command to copy and paste selections based on a cells values. Please see below for the example code.

What i am struggling with is the entry destination then inputting data into the row below.
The function works when used in bulk, but on repeated use, it will overwrite the data already in row 34 and then continue overwriting the rows below.

What would be best for this purpose? a counta command or a row.count? And if so, how would i write it?

```
Sub x115()

Dim r As Long, endRow As Long, pasteRowIndex As Long, y As Range

endRow = 31 ' last row

pasteRowIndex = 34 ' Entry Row but the range needs to be between B34 and B64

Set y = ActiveSheet.Range("B:M")

For r = 1 To endRow 'Loop through activesheet and search for 115
    If Cells(r, "B").Value = 115 Then 'Found



        'Copy the current row

        Intersect(y, Rows(r)).Copy Cells(pasteRowIndex, 2)
        Intersect(y, Rows(r)).ClearContents

        pasteRowIndex = pasteRowIndex + 1



End If

Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: What happens if the last row determined by `Rows.Count` is greater than 64?

Comment: The idea was to restrict the count to be between rows 34 to 64 so it wouldn't go over. there wouldn't be enough data entries to go over the total

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the `LastRow` dynamically, for Column A:

```
Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = Sheets.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row.
' the 1 in Cells(Row.Count, 1) indicates column 1 which is  A
```

If I understand correctly, you want the 115 value to be inserted to the next blank row on Column B, you could assign the `pasteRowIndex` the same way like so:

```
Dim pasteRowIndex As Long

pasteRowIndex = Sheets.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row.
' the 2 in Cells(Row.Count, 1) indicates column 1 which is B
```

If the `pasteRowIndex` must be between rows rows 34 and 64 put in an `If...Then...Else` statement. Something like:

```
If pasteRowIndex < 34 Or pasteRowIndex > 64 Then
    MsgBox "PasteRowIndex =" & pasteRowIndex  & vbNewLine & "It must be between rows 34 and 64."
    Exit Sub
Else
    'Continue with procedure.
End If
```

Same principle with a static range:

```
Dim pasteRowIndex As Long

pasteRowIndex = Sheets.Cells(64, 2).End(xlUp).Row.
'You could change Cells(64, 2) with Range("B64") too.
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but i was wondering if it was possible to restrict a rows.count or counta function between a defined range and only count those rows. The range in mind being "B34:B64"

Comment: @Diver367 I've edited the answer to take into account your comment.

Comment: @samuel_Everson The static range code worked perfectly, thank you for the help